# Adding custom attributes to an asp:CheckBox control

Tags: asp.net, custom-attributes, html

I am trying to add a custom data-required attribute to an asp Checkbox control, it works fine for all other controls I've used it on, but on checkboxs it renders the checkbox inside a span that has the custom attribute on. I've tried adding the attribute in the markup and tried adding it to the control in the code behind. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that is a bummer ... if it's just rendering like that, I'm inclined to think you might have to re-write the control, or at least override its "Render" method or something.  Have you considered a client-side hack, adding the attribute by Javascript after the page loads?

Comment: @dbaseman CheckBox control has collections for adding attributes to the rendered span and for the rendered input also

Comment: @AdrianIftode nice!  Good thing I don't work for tom, eh?

Comment: That's worked great, thanks! I didn't think it should be difficult, I hoped was just missing something.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use [InputAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

Here is the code I have used:

```
cb.InputAttributes.Add("data-group", "chkbox");
```

Then you can use JQuery to target all check-boxes.

```
 $("*[data-group='chkbox']").prop("checked", true);
```