# Jquery: selector for elements that don't exist now, but will exist in future?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

In in aspx page, there is a grid view, that has template control for checkbox, something like this

```
<asp:gridview .....
  <columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server"/>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

Now if I write something like

```
$(#'<%=chkSelect.ClientID%>').something( function() {});
```

I get an error saying 'chkSelect doesn't exists in current context, which is pretty obvious, because this element will exist when griddata is loaded, what I have done is bind the change events of the checkbox to a delegate..

```
$("body").delegate(":checkbox", "change", function () {
                custList = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () { return $(this).closest('tr').find('.grdCustName').text() }).get();
                $('#<%=hdnFromCustomer.ClientID %>').val(custList);
            }
```

which is again working as it should, the problem is I need to know if a checkbox with a particular id (for ex here, `chkAll`) is changed(clicked), then select all checkbox, checking all in not an issue, I can do this with something like `$(':checkbox').attr(checked, 'on')` or something.

But the problem is, if I write 
`$('#<%=chkAll.ClientID %>')`, it doesn't allows me to, because this checkbox isn't present in DOM at time of start, but will be available when user clicks `showReport` button and grid is populated.

So, basically, my question is how can I select, or what selector should I use to select this checkbox (or any other element) in DOM that doesn't exist but will exist at some time in future?

**EDIT:** In response to some answers, the problem is not binding, I HAVE DONE SO by using `delegate()`, which I also could have done by using `.on()` or `.live()`. The problem is as as `Felix Kling` commented, he hit the nail on the head, (read his comment(s) and my reply to him). The problem is the *element doesn't exists* in the DOM at page startup time. *It is build dynamically* when user clicks the `showReport` button, and gridview is populated with data, *this is where this element is created*. Though I approach described by `Yoeri` may/may not work, I wanna know *is there any possible way (by jQuery of course!) that I could select such an element as described in this case*, or is my only option to look for like alternative like the one `Yoeri` answered?

Comment: 'chkSelect doesn't exists in current context' - is this JS message? I've never seen jQuery showing such messages. It just silently do nothing.

Comment: use jquery live() http://api.jquery.com/live/ or on as of jquery 1.7

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem with using `.delegate` (or `.on` for that matter) if it works? *edit:* ah, now I see... at the moment you bind the event handler, you don't even know the ID. The approach you choose is fine in general, but fails here because of .NET.

Comment: jQuery live is good, but it is deprecated and will be removed soon. So `delegate` or `on`

Comment: I don't know .NET but you should try to give the element a fixed ID (if that's possible) and use that ID instead.

Comment: @FAngel:
No its not jQuery message, its shown by asp.net page when I load it in the browser!

Comment: @FelixKling:
I may even think about getting the id of current checkbox in the delegate, but to what point? I would still need it to compare to `chkAll.ClientID` in a `if()` clause, but as soon as I write `<%= chkAll.ClientID %>`, I would still get `chkSelect doesn't exists in current page` error.
soo... you have a solution for this?

Comment: $("#I_beleave_this_does_not_exists") - try this in your console - you will find that it returns just an empty aray. But no  messages. Can you please show the part of JS code which is produced here `$(#'<%=chkSelect.ClientID%>').something( function() {});`? What do you see here in browser

Comment: @Razort4x: Getting the ID inside the handler won't work either. The .NET code is evaluated on the server side, i.e. `<%= chkAll.ClientID %>` is evaluated *before* it is sent to the client, not when the JavaScript code is executed. And apparently at that moment that element does not exist yet. That's why you get that error message (it must be a .NET error message).

Comment: @FelixKling:
Yep: you got the point exactly. I even updated the question to reflect the same!

Comment: As I said (or implied), just give it another unique attribute... for example a unique class name. Then you can do `$("body").delegate(".unique-class", "change", ....)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not selecting the chkAll box on a custom attribute or class?

I often use an action attribute to bind event to ... just to keep all things consistent and seperated from css classes (which are not for binding behaviour to it but for style ;-)

```
<input type="check" action="checkAll"
...
$('input[action=checkAll]').delegate(....)
```

As for adding an action attribute, you can look here ... (to avoid adding an extra span element)
[adding-custom-attributes-to-an-aspcheckbox-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939287/adding-custom-attributes-to-an-aspcheckbox-control)

Comment: The OP seems to know about this, he used `.delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

When working in WebForms I use the ends with selector a lot.  In your case the selector you're looking for would read:

```
$("input[id$='checkAll']")
```

Alternatively if you're using WebForms 4.0 you can set the [client id mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) on the checkbox to static and you can get a relatively sane id to hard code as your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the build & run the jquery code from the .net code behind.

The code in this Gist will help make it quick & easy: https://gist.github.com/3415335